# How I know actual kernel stable on Loki 0.4.1?

Tags: release-loki, kernel

How I know actual kernel stable version on Loki 0.4.1? Actually, my kernel version is Linux 4.10.0-27.

UPDATE:
23/01/2018 - 4.13.0-31-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: Unless you have purposely installed a different version elementary will be running the LTS kernel whichever that happens to be at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most current kernel release is 4.8.0.56. 4.10 is not the LTS kernel.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the stable version is 4.8.0.58 to Elementary OS Loki 0.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 is now on kernel 4.10.x

It has reached 17.04, which is on 4.10x.

Ubuntu will soon release a new ISO of 16.04.3 LTS The Kernel is already out.

So, if you did a dist-upgrade trough the Terminal, you're also on that kernel.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A16.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support

Comment: Actually the eOS Kernel is the 4.8.0-58, stable for now. Thanks for the explantion.

Answer (score -2):

See https://www.kernel.org

mainline:   4.15-rc9
stable:     4.14.14
longterm:   4.9.77
longterm:   4.4.112

etc